# Potty training a two year old

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My daughter turned two in May and didn’t want to wear diapers anymore. We decided to let her walk around naked at home and she would run to the potty as soon as she had to go but never tell us until after she went. That was fine at home but we had a problem when we would go out because she wouldn’t tell us until after she went in her pants. It’s been 4 months and now she’s in underwear all day but diaper at night(never has accidents durning naps and usually has a super light diaper in the morning) but she doesn’t tell us she has to go until she pees a little in her underwear and then says she has to go. I rarely ask her if she has to go unless we are out and about passing a bathroom. Should I be asking her more? Am I expecting to much? Tell me the tricks!  She’s not even 2.5 but I’m so sick of going through so much underwear in one day.It doesn’t happen if she has to poop. She knows that feeling and will tell us.

Answer (score 4):

Empirically, it sounds like she gets too distracted when out to want to take a potty break.  It probably doesn't help that she can't just walk away and go like she can at your house.  You probably need to take over scheduling potty breaks when out.  Don't ask her, just announce that you both will take a potty break.

Comment: This is what we do when out. We all stop and take a trip to the toilets. Toddler gets option to go with mummy or daddy.